# Extracting a URL from hyperlinked text in Excel cell

Tags: c#, .net, excel, hyperlink, vsto

I have a table full of Hyperlinked text in excel, so it's basically a bunch of names but when I click on one, it takes me to some URL in my default browser.

So I am extracting text from this excel table in my program, but the value I get when I extract from these hyperlink cells is that of the string inside, when I want the URL the string is linked to in the excel file.

So I'm thinking there are two ways to do this. Either I can convert all the hyperlinked text in the excel file to the corresponding URLs, or I can use C# to somehow extract the URL value from the cell and not the text.

I don't know how to do either of these things, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

C# code so far:

```
Excel.ApplicationClass excelApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

//excelApp.Visible = true;

Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = 
excelApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\use\\Desktop\\list.xls",
0, false, 5, "", "",false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "", 
true, false, 0, true, false, false);

Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;

string currentSheet = "Sheet1";
Excel.Worksheet xlws = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(currentSheet);

string myString = ((Excel.Range)xlws.Cells[2, 1]).Value.ToString();
```

As for the excel file, it's just one long row of names hyperlinked. For instance cell A2 would contain the text:

[Yummy cookie recipe](http://allrecipes.com//Recipes/desserts/cookies/Main.aspx)

And I want to extract the string:

```
http://allrecipes.com//Recipes/desserts/cookies/Main.aspx
```

Comment: Show excel example and some code

Comment: I showed code, but the excel file is just one column of hyperlinked text with entries exactly like the cookie example shown above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a vba macro:

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor and paste in the following:

```vb
Function URL(rg As Range) As String
  Dim Hyper As Hyperlink
  Set Hyper = rg.Hyperlinks.Item(1)
  URL = Hyper.Address
End Function
```

And then you can use it in your Worksheet, like this:

`=URL(B4)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just used this to extract all the links to a different part of the table using my program, and then I copy/pasted them to a new excel table. Messy, but the end result is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 8):

In your code just add

```
string myString = ((Excel.Range)xlws.Cells[2, 1]).Cells.Hyperlinks[1].Address;
```

I obviously recommend doing some checks before accessing the "Hyperlinks" property.

Comment: This is the best answer from a coding perspective. It does not require modifying the excel worksheet. I found it necessary to change xlws.Cells to xlws.Sheets[1].Cells.

Answer (score 5):

VBA function:

1. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> (Opens Visual Basic Editor)
2. Click on Insert -> Module (adds a module to your excel file)
3. Paste the code below for the function of GETURL
4. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> (Closes the Visual Basic Editor)

Now use the `=GETURL(cell)` to get the URL
*Example: `=GETURL(A1)` will return the URL for the Hyperlink displayed in cell A1*

```vb
Function GETURL(HyperlinkCell As Range)
    GETURL = HyperlinkCell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

[Source](http://www.bohack.com/2009/06/get-the-url-from-a-hyperlink-in-excel/)

Answer (score 2):

Use Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) to open Excel workbook and extract all hyperlinks.

---

I put a hyperlink into A1 of Sheet1 in Book1.xlsx: text = "example.com, address = "http://www.example.com"

```
_Application app = null;
try
{
    app = new Application();

    string path = @"c:\temp\Book1.xlsx";
    var workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

    var sheets = workbook.Worksheets;
    var sheet = (Worksheet)sheets.get_Item("Sheet1");

    var range = sheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
    var hyperlinks = range.Cells.Hyperlinks.OfType<Hyperlink>();

    foreach (var h in hyperlinks)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("text: {0}, address: {1}", h.TextToDisplay, h.Address);
    }
}
finally
{
    if (app != null)
        app.Quit();
}
```

Output:

```
text: example.com, address: http://www.example.com/
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer but the syntax was not working on my system and I got the job done more on the excel side of things using my C# program just a little.

Comment: @AJ: What version of Excel and VSTO do you use? I used the latest, .NET 4.0/VS 2010/Excel 14

Comment: I'm using excel 2003. The program is actually all done now, and is generating a database. But since there are 2700 entries, it might take around 7 to 10 hours to finish >_>

Answer (score 0):

why not use Uri class to convert string into URL:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://myUrl/test.html");
```

Comment: How do you get the string URL from the hyperlinked column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBA code to achieve this.
Press `Alt` + `F11` to open VB editor,  Insert a `Module` and paste the code below:

```
Sub run()    
    On Error Resume Next    

    For Each hLink In Selection    
        Range(hLink.Address).Offset(0, 1) = hLink.Hyperlinks(1).Address    
    Next    
End Sub
```

Save your excel file[in excel 2007 and above save as macro enabled...]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Excel.Application appExcel = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbooks workBooks = appExcel.Workbooks;
Excel.Workbook excelSheet = workBooks.Open("......EditPath", false, ReadOnly: true);

foreach (Excel.Worksheet worksheet in excelSheet.Worksheets)
{
    Excel.Hyperlinks hyperLinks = worksheet.Hyperlinks;
    foreach (Excel.Hyperlink lin in hyperLinks)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("# LINK: adress:" + lin.Address);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into this issue and this is what worked for me:

I used the FormulaR1C1 extension method for a range.  So my code looked like this:

```
                    for (int r = 2; r <= sheetRange.Rows.Count; r++)
                    {
                        documentRecord = new List<string>();
                        for (int c = 1; c <= wkCol; c++)
                        {
                            documentRecord.Add(sheetRange.Cells[r, c].FormulaR1C1); 
                        }
                        AllRecords.Add(documentRecord);
                    }
```

When the record is added to the list of records, the value of whatever the cell range was is formatted into a clickable-hyperlink.